# Where in the bible explicitly did Jesus say he is God?

Tags: life-of-jesus, words-of-jesus

It is known to all that back then there are people that worship (non)living things such as the sun/moon or a dead notable person. It is also known that most if not all, of those things/person never even claimed to be the God, however, their followers do.

Did Jesus every say explicitly that he is God? I do not accept statements that are not explicit because

1. It's of the words of the writer or other people.

or

2. It can be interpreted in a different way.

Unlike explicit statements, it can't interpreted in a different way and it doesn't require you to know the context and stuff.

Answer (score -3):

We see Jesus telling the High Priest before the public at Mk 41:62=63 that He is indeed the Son of God :

"Again the high priest asked him, “Are you the Messiah, the Son of the Blessed One?”   Jesus said, “I am; and

‘you will see the Son of Man
seated at the right hand of the Power,’
and ‘coming with the clouds of heaven.’”

Comment: What are you trying to point out? Quoting random scripture isn't very helpful - esp. as none of them even reference the Q